# How to get the return code of RTP from the shell in Vxworks?

Tags: shell, return-value, vxworks

In Linux, there are very convenient mechanisms for retrieving the return code of a program from the shell.  In particular, the shell provides the `$?` variable and the `if` construct.

Is there any way to also get the return codes (i.e. the return value of `main`) of RTPs spawned interactively from the vxworks shell?  I'd be interested in doing this from either the standard "c interpreter shell" ("->"), or the RTP command shell.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to grab the return value (from kernel space, which is where CMD shell and C shell live) of an RTP. You can obviously achieve what you want with kernel tasks, but that entails first getting your symbols into the kernel either directly, or by a DKM (downloadable kernel module).